# Probability of reaching to point at a distance n

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A North-South white line is drawn in a school ground. At first, you are 5 meter due west
from a point A on the line. You toss a coin, and if it is head move 1 meter east. If it is tail,
move 1 meter north. Note that once you reach the line you must stop. Let *Pn* be the
probability that you stop at the point *n* meters north from A. Find the sum of values of
n for which *Pn* is maximum.

I tried to make some recurring relation but could not reach to a solution. Is there any other method or how can we make a recurring relation

Please help.

Comment: Sorry that was  a typo error

Comment: You need to find a formula for $P(n)$.  It turns out there are two values of $n$ that yield the same (maximum) value of $P(n)$.  You can find them by testing your formula on the inequality $P(n+1)/P(n)\geq 1$.  To find $P(n)$, you observe that you have $n+5$ locations and you need to fill them with either N or E (the last one is of course E).  For example if $n=8$ then NNNENNNENENEE is a possibility.